# Validating Input string with Exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception

I coded the following java snippet. I want to throw, catch and handle exception if user enters value other than "A","B" or "C". I  know this can be done without exception but my task is to implement this with exception. The following code catches exception but the problem is that even if I enter value from A,B or C.It still executes the Catch block. Kindly share where i am wrong.

```
boolean invalid = false;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter:");
            t = in.nextLine();
            invalid=true;
            if(!t.equals("A") || !t.equals("B") || !t.equals("C")){
                invalid=false;
                throw new InputMismatchException("Invalid!");
            }

        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Enter from options.");
            invalid = false;
            
        }
    }while(!invalid);
```

Comment: `if(!t.equals("A") && !t.equals("B") && !t.equals("C")){`

Comment: Here is another way: `if (! List.of("A", "B", "C").contains(t)) { ... }` - requires Java SE 9. This is useful in case you have more strings to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is **if** condition, when you enter **A**, the *first condition* will be **false**, but *second condition* will be **true**, because **t** equals to **A** not **B** therefore *second condition* will be **true**, if one of the conditions is **true**, whole *if condition* will be **true** because this is **OR** statement. Therefore, *if block* will be executed.

try to change it to the following (**AND** statement)

```
if(!t.equals("A") && !t.equals("B") && !t.equals("C"))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to throw, catch and handle exception if user enters value other than "A","B" or "C"

This can be coded in different ways, and this syntax is useful in case you have more values to compare:

```
// Using Java 8 Streams
if (Stream.of("A", "B", "C").noneMatch(e -> e == t)) { ...
// Using Java 7 Collections
if (! Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C").contains(t)) { ...
// Using Java 9 Collections
if (! List.of("A", "B", "C").contains(t)) { ...
```